# Varnish - Multiple backends with same hostname

Tags: varnish, magento

I have several Magento 2 instances under the same domain. For example, www.mydomain.com/magento1 and www.mydomain.com/magento2.

I am trying to set up Varnish against these Magento sites. However, how can I set up multiple backends if the sites are essentially using the same hostname? So, this example I've found for handling multiple backends, won't work for me.

```
 backend example1 {
     .host = "backend.example1.com";
     .port = "8080";
 }
 backend example2 {
      .host = "backend.example2.com";
      .port = "8080";
 }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Even if from a vcl point of view, you could setup fancy regex to cache based on url, setting a backend usually require unique hostname. Since i presume your not in production with Magento running in a subfolder, i suggest you to move each magento to subdomain, eg www.mydomain.com/mag1 --> mag1.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

In the vcl_recv() subrutine you can change the backend depending on the URI, for example this works in Varnish 4:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^(?i)/magento1") {
        set req.backend_hint = example1;
    }
    if (req.url ~ "^(?i)/magento2") {
        set req.backend_hint = example2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define the backends with IP address instead of hostname. Or use some in-house hostname for those machines along with the real hostnames.